# "Call to Me and I will answer you, and I will tell you great and mighty things, which you do not know" - To whom is Jeremiah 33:3's promise made?

Tags: referent-identification, jeremiah

Jeremiah 33:1-3 (NASB):

> Then the word of the LORD came to Jeremiah the second time, while he was still confined in the courtyard of the guard, saying, 2 “This is what the LORD says, He who made the earth, the LORD who formed it to create it, He whose name is the LORD: 3 **‘Call to Me and I will answer you, and I will tell you great and mighty things, which you do not know**.

1. Who is being addressed in verse 3? To whom is the promise made? Does it apply to all future God's servants to come?
2. What does the promise actually mean?

Comment: I feel like close vote for poor quality, but haven't yet. The Q seems very repeatative and spam like.

Comment: @Michael16 - you would need to close-vote tons of questions I've asked (and that other people have asked as well) :-)

Answer (score 1):

The entire chapter of Jer 33 appears to God/the LORD speaking to the prophet Jeremiah **about** the following:

- V4 - Israel, this city (Jerusalem), the kings of Judah,
- V6 - this people the Jews,
- V7 - Judah
- V9 - this city (Jerusalem)
- V10 - this place, Jerusalem
- V13 - the surrounding hills of Benjamin, around Jerusalem
- V14 - the house of Israel and Judah
- V17 - the throne of David
- V18 - the levites

... and so forth.  Thus, God appears to be trying to encourage Jeremiah with promises, that, despite the gloomy outlook, better days are ahead for Jerusalem and the remnant people of God.

Naturally, **Jeremiah relayed this encouraging message to those in Jerusalem** and recorded it for us to read today.  Verses 2 & 3 appear to be a reminder that God is great, omniscient but still interested and attentive to His people.  God and can will do great things, especially for the people of God.

More specifically, the "great and unsearchable things you do not know" are things yet to be revealed to Jeremiah about the future.  The rest of the book of Jeremiah is testament to the veracity and fulfillment of this promise.

Comment: So the promise was just for Jeremiah, and it would be incorrect to claim that this was promised to anyone else, correct?

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator - That is NOT what I said - read it again - God spoke to Jeremiah in the first person whose job, as a prophet, was to relay the message to all others because the promises were for these "others" such as the citizens of Jerusalem, etc.

Answer (score 0):

King James Bible Jeremiah 33:

> 1Moreover the word of the LORD came unto **Jeremiah** the second time, while he was yet shut up in the court of the prison, saying, 2Thus saith the LORD the maker thereof, the LORD that formed it, to establish it; the LORD is his name; 3Call unto me, and I will answer **thee**, and shew **thee** great and mighty things, which **thou** knowest not.

Who is being addressed in verse 3? To whom is the promise made?

All the pronouns are singular, referring to Jeremiah.

Does it apply to all future God's servants to come?

Four chapters earlier, God promised Jeremiah in 29:

> 10For thus saith the LORD, That after seventy years be accomplished at Babylon I will visit you, and perform my good word toward you, in causing you to return to this place. 11For I know the thoughts that I think toward you, saith the LORD, thoughts of peace, and not of evil, to give you an expected end. 12Then shall **ye call upon me**, and **ye shall go and pray unto me**, and I will hearken unto you. 13And **ye shall seek me, and find me**, when ye shall search for me with all your heart. 14And I will be found of you, saith the LORD: and I will turn away your captivity, and I will gather you from all the nations, and from all the places whither I have driven you, saith the LORD; and I will bring you again into the place whence I caused you to be carried away captive.

Here the pronouns are plural referring to the Israelites.

Both passages encourage people of God to pray to him. However, the resultant promises were different.

What does the promise actually mean?

To God's prophets, God promised to reveal them great and mighty things.

To God's people in general, God promised not to reject them if they would call on him.

This bears out even in the OT. Jesus says in John 6:

> 37b whoever comes to me I will never drive away.

Answer (score 0):

Q1a: Who is being addressed in verse 3? The answer is obviously Jeremiah, to whom God revealed His message.

Q1b: To whom is the promise made? In this particular context, again is Jeremiah.

Q1c: Does it apply to all future God's servants to come? Apparently Yes, and this answer I need to explain.

Jeremiah 33:3 NIV

> ‘Call to me and I will answer you and tell you great and unsearchable things you do not know.’

Compare Jeremiah 33:3 with the following verses found in NT;

> Ask and it will be given to you; seek and you will find; knock and the door will be opened to you. (Matthew 7:7 NIV)

> Whoever has will be given more, and they will have an abundance. (Matthew 13:12; 25:29 NIV)

> But when he, the **Spirit of truth**, comes, he will guide you into all the truth. (John 16:13a NIV)

> 9 However, as it is written: “What no eye has seen, what no ear has heard,
> and what no human mind has conceived”—the things God has prepared for those who love him— 10 these are the things God has revealed to us by **his Spirit**. (1 Corinthians 2:9-10 NIV)

The Lord is just. There is no double standard in Him. Jeremiah would not be the only one the Lord gave this promise. Whoever faithful to Him will be treated the same. Clearly this promise is fulfilled by the Holy Spirit.

Q2: What does the promise actually mean? It means whoever faithful to the Lord, the Lord Spirit will be with them, and guide them into all the truth, the mystery since the creation (Jeremiah 33:2)